# are typings functional across files?

Tags: python, dataframe, type-hinting

I'm declaring and type hinting a function with an optional param which should be a DataFrame. However I can't get python type-hinting to give any warnings / type checking support.

This is before getting into column types, just the fact of a DataFrame is not a Dict level..

```
# file 1

    def write_bq(self, df: pd.DataFrame = None, delete_first=True):
```

and in another file I call it with the *wrong* type.
but it seems there is no linting support for this?

```
# file2 (actually a subclass) 

        updated: List[Dict] = []
        self.write_bq(updated)
```

There's no warning except for at runtime.

```
pylint cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

and `mypy` just complains about standard import libraries but happily skips over my broken code.

```
mypy cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py 
cxutils/gbot.py:11: error: Skipping analyzing 'httplib2': found module but no type hints or library stubs
cxutils/logit.py:10: error: Skipping analyzing 'google.cloud': found module but no type hints or library stubs
# ... etc.
```

I'm a heavy typescript user, but always having trouble beyond basic types with python type hints.

Any suggestions on the above?
I assume i'm missing something in the configuration. I started adding a `mypy.ini` to try and skip the missing configs but that doesn't seem to be getting applied.
Running inside a virtual env, so assume the active venv mypy would take before anything global... `which mypy` confirms this.

update: I can skip the imports with a cmd line flag but still the errors aren't found

```
mypy cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py --ignore-missing-imports
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

with `--verbose` I can see it is indeed looking at my file.

```
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ mypy -v cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py --ignore-missing-imports

LOG:  Mypy Version:           0.812
LOG:  Config File:            mypy.ini
LOG:  Configured Executable:  /home/dcollier/dev/kzen/venv/bin/python3
LOG:  Current Executable:     /home/dcollier/dev/kzen/venv/bin/python3
LOG:  Cache Dir:              .mypy_cache
LOG:  Compiled:               True
LOG:  Exclude:                
LOG:  Found source:           BuildSource(path='cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py', module='cxutils.digger.chat_stat', has_text=False, base_dir='/home/dcollier/dev/kzen')
LOG:  Metadata fresh for cxutils.digger.chat_stat: file cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py
LOG:  Metadata fresh for cxutils.digger: file /home/dcollier/dev/kzen/cxutils/digger/__init__.py
LOG:  Metadata fresh for cxutils: file /home/dcollier/dev/kzen/cxutils/__init__.py
```

etc

[update2]

I tried a very simple test with passing an int to a string, so it seems actually type checking in general is completely borked.

```
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ which mypy
/home/dcollier/dev/kzen/venv/bin/mypy

(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ mypy tests/type_hints_test.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ cat tests/type_hints_test.py 

"""
testing type hinting
"""


def echo(msg: str):
    """simple echo"""
    assert isinstance(msg, str), 'Argument of wrong type!'
    print(msg)


def test_hints():
    """hints"""
    value: int = 10
    echo(value)



(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ python -V
Python 3.9.2
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ mypy -V
mypy 0.812
```

note i'm running 3.9 locally but plan to deploy on 3.8 so trying to keep to old style `List[x]` rather than `list(x)`. Not that I'm that familiar with the finer points of type hints...

FWIW the unit test will fail the assertion, but the type hints don't smell anything wrong.

```
    def echo(msg: str):
        """simple echo"""
>       assert isinstance(msg, str), 'Argument of wrong type!'
E       AssertionError: Argument of wrong type!
E       assert False
E        +  where False = isinstance(10, str)

tests/type_hints_test.py:8: AssertionError
========================= short test summary info =========================
FAILED tests/type_hints_test.py::test_hints - AssertionError: Argument o...
============================ 1 failed in 0.08s ============================
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ mypy tests/type_hints_test.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think mypy has the option to check multiple files at once instead of once and I assume that by default it doesn't check the code of other files that may be used by your main code (I don't know if this is understandable or not)

Comment: You don't say what development environment you are using. In Python, type hints are *hints*. Python is not strongly typed, and of itself it will not give you type warnings. That depends on your IDE. PyCharm will, but IDLE won't. As far as I know, `pylint` doesn't know about type hints either. It may be that coming from a Typescript background you have unmet expectations about how Python type hinting works.

Comment: Did you get an error from mypy saying `error: Skipping analyzing 'pandas': found module but no type hints or library stubs`?

Comment: @dcsan you need to pass the flag `--check-untyped-defs` to force mypy to check the body of functions that do not have any annotations

Comment: OK finally! So it's basically disabled by default for typed parameter checking? the func and it's call are both using type hinted params... I guess I assumed that would get checked \0/

Comment: if you want to put an answer I'm happy to accept @IainShelvington